# how to convet this the code into a loop to be less repetitive

Tags: r, excel, loops

```
JUNE_2019_1 <- read_excel("G:/19011/2019 SALES/JUN 2019 P1.xlsx")
JUNE_2019_2 <- read_excel("G:/19011/2019 SALES/JUN 2019 P2.xlsx")
JUNE_2019_3 <- read_excel("G:/19011/2018 SALES/JUN 2019 P3.xlsx")

JULY_2019_1 <- read_excel("G:/19011/2019 SALES/JUL 2019 P1.xlsx")
JULY_2019_2 <- read_excel("G:/19011/2019 SALES/JUL 2019 P2.xlsx")
JULY_2019_3 <- read_excel("G:/19011/2019 SALES/JUL 2019 P3.xlsx")

AUG_2019_1 <- read_excel("G:/19011/2019 SALES/AUG 2019 P1.xlsx")
AUG_2019_2 <- read_excel("G:/19011/2019 SALES/AUG 2019 P2.xlsx")
AUG_2019_3 <- read_excel("G:/19011/2019 SALES/AUG 2019 P3.xlsx")

SEP_2019_1 <- read_excel("G:/19011/2019 SALES/sep 2019 P1.xlsx")
SEP_2019_2 <- read_excel("G:/19011/2019 SALES/sep 2019 P2.xlsx")
SEP_2019_3 <- read_excel("G:/19011/2019 SALES/SEP 2019 P3.xlsx")

OCT_2019_1 <- read_excel("G:/19011/2019 SALES/oct 2019 P1.xlsx")
OCT_2019_2 <- read_excel("G:/19011/2019 SALES/oct 2019 P2.xlsx")
OCT_2019_3 <- read_excel("G:/19011/2019 SALES/OCT 2019 P3.xlsx")
OCT_2019_4 <- read_excel("G:/19011/2019 SALES/OCT 2019 P4.xlsx")

NOV_2019_1 <- read_excel("G:/19011/2019 SALES/NOV 2019 P1.xlsx")
NOV_2019_2 <- read_excel("G:/19011/2019 SALES/NOV 2019 P2.xlsx")
NOV_2019_3 <- read_excel("G:/19011/2019 SALES/NOV 2019 P3.xlsx")

DEC_2019_1 <- read_excel("G:/19011/2019 SALES/DEC 2019 P1.xlsx")
DEC_2019_2 <- read_excel("G:/19011/2019 SALES/DEC 2019 P2.xlsx")
DEC_2019_3 <- read_excel("G:/19011/2019 SALES/DEC 2019 P3.xlsx")
```

This code need to be in a loop loading this files into my workspace can anyone help 
This code need to be in a loop loading this files into my workspace can anyone help

my path is ("G:/19011/2019 SALES/") and I am still stuck in this

Answer (score 0):

We can get all the files from the folder into a `list`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)
files <- list.files("G:/19011/2019 SALES/", pattern = "\\.xlsx", full.names  = TRUE)
lst1 <- map(files, read_excel)
```

Comment: it gives me a list of zero

Comment: @SepaMostafa you meant `files` didn't show value.  Please show the contents of `files`

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: @SepaMostafa I meant what is the values in `files`

Comment: character(empty) that is the result in files

Comment: @SepaMostafa I am assuming that the directory you showed is the correct path i.e. `"G:/19011/2019 SALES/"`

Comment: no I am loading from this path but it is not my current directory

Comment: @SepaMostafa yes, i meant if you use the `path = ""G:/19011/2019 SALES/"` in `list.files`, it should get all the files from that path.  Not clear why it is not working for you

Comment: @SepaMostafa For e.g. if I do `list.files("/Users/akrun/Documents")` it lists all the files in my Documents folder.  It seems that the whitespaces in your folder name could be a problem

Comment: Also, I am using MacOS.

Comment: no  now it lists the files from the working directory  not from the path

Comment: @SepaMostafa  Not entirely sure about the issue in your side.  Can you set the working directory to `setwd("G:/19011/2019 SALES/")` and then do `list.files(pattern = "\\.xlsx$")`

Comment: The working directory was changed to G:/19011/2019 SALES inside a notebook chunk. The working directory will be reset when the chunk is finished running. Use the knitr root.dir option in the setup chunk to change the working directory for notebook chunks.

Comment: it gives me that and still listing the files in the old directory

Comment: @SepaMostafa the issue is that there is some disconnect in the notebook regarding the working directory or the directory you want to set

Comment: yeah I am trying to search for a solution if you find sth please let me knoe

Comment: @SepaMostafa sure, please do update your post with all the info.  You mentioned about the notebook and stuff only in the comments.  When people try to answer only basesd on the content of your question, the natural way is to do the obvious i.e. specify the path and pattern